# Write a function for a river word problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, word-problem

My problem:

> The river flows at 1.5 meters per second.
>
> Write a rational function rule for the total time required to travel a distance $d$ downstream and back in a river flowing at a rate $v_r$.

I'm not really sure what it means with the $v_r$. Also, what does it mean if the velocity is equal to the speed of the river?

Would you solve this by doing

$$T=(v-1.5)d+(v+1.5)d?$$

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: It is easier than that. In one direction the river works with you and in the other it works against you so you can freeze the river.

Comment: The units show your equation cannot be right.  The left side has units of time, the right has units of distance^2/time.  Think about distance=velocity*time  You have the right idea that the velocity downstream is $v+1.5$ and upstream is $v-1.5$  Maybe you are expected to write the equation using $v_r$ for the velocity of the river and substitute in $1.5$ at the end.

Comment: @RossMillikan Do you possibly know what that would be? I'm not sure of the equation, we haven't done a problem like this.

Comment: The time is $T=\frac d{v+v_r}+\frac d{v-v_r}$.  The first term is the time to go with the current, the second is the time against the current.  Note the units work here.

Answer (score 0):

For a river flowing at v ft/min, the distance d, travel in t min is d = vt.
The time it takes to travel a distance of d is t = v/d.

As no other means of propulsion are provided, the time it takes to return is unfathomable.